# Rails Ransack include blank in multiple select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I'm using the gem Ransack in a Rails 3.2 app.

The following works to select multiple values:

```
<td><%= f.collection_select :costproject_coststatus_id_in, Coststatus.all, :id, :statuscode, {}, { :multiple => true}
```

But, is there a way to include a blank?

I've tried these:

```
<td><%= f.collection_select :costproject_coststatus_id_in, Coststatus.all, :id, :statuscode, {}, { :multiple => true, :include_blank => true }%></td>

<td><%= f.collection_select :costproject_coststatus_id_in, Coststatus.all, :id, :statuscode, include_blank: true, {}, { :multiple => true }%></td>
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: It should work `<td><%= f.collection_select :costproject_coststatus_id_in, Coststatus.all, :id, :statuscode, include_blank: true%></td>`

Comment: Arup - that works. But, it doesn't when I add the `multiple => true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - this worked:

```
<td><%= f.collection_select :costproject_coststatus_id_in, Coststatus.all, :id, :statuscode, {:include_blank => true}, { :multiple => true }%></td>
```

Comment: thanks @Reddirt do you know how to make it automatically select all from the very beginning.?